# mod_rewrite is disabled but /index still loads

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with mod_rewrite and I cannot understand what is wrong.

First I did a query string rewrite to have something like this:

```
/api/call
```

instead of

```
/api.php/call.php
```

This did not work as when printing the request, it was empty, whereas if I enter the url

```
/api/call/test=5
```

the request parameters returns with test=5

I added the Allow from all in the virtual host but it still did not work.

I then tried to disable mod_rewrite and to my amazement the call /api still loaded /api.php and /index loaded /index.html.

This is really strange as this is not supposed to happen if mod_rewrite is disabled. In fact, if I try it on my local WAMP server, a 404 not found is shown.

This means that somewhere there is some sort of rewrite on the Ubuntu server but I cannot understand how this is working with mod_rewrite being disabled.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT (sites-available contents)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Apache was restarted successfully with restart not reload.

Comment: Please post what contains in your `<Directory>` directive for that location from your conf file.

Comment: I also would like to ask if you restarted the server properly.

Comment: Check if `mod_negotiate` is enabled. Together with `MultiViews` this could lead to the loading of `api.php` and `index.html`

Comment: @tlenss Great now we are getting somewhere as it is not resolving. However now I tried to re-enable mod_rewrite and the query string rule is not working. I am sure that this works as it worked fine on localhost using WAMP.

Comment: can you post the contents of your .htaccess ?

Comment: @tlenss just posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `MultiViews` enabled on `/var/www`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews

Comment: I tried removing MultiViews from /var/www. After turning off the negotiation module, a 404 error is still being thrown when accessing the urls in /api/call format.

Comment: @seedeg Your original question was "why does index.html load when I type /index?"  That's because of MultiViews.  So, that part is solved.  You should update your question, reenable mod_rewrite and get the /api rewrites going.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

```
a2dismod rewrite
```

Then restart apache. Also make sure there is no .htaccess file in the root directory specifying mod-rewrite settings.

Comment: Tried that. /index still resolves to /index.html with mod_rewrite disabled and no .htaccess file.

Comment: oh yeah look below for the multiviews comment. I think that is your answer.